# Create shapes by for loop in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, object, canvas

EDIT:i will post all my code the html and js,and excuse me for too many comments

I am trying to create rectangles in canvas by for loop (there is input user)
and I want to access them in another function to do some stuff,
the main problem is how to access the shapes's name after loop I have tried this but when i call them in another function it gives me,

> undefined "object name"

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;




var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

//drawing the base off the towers
var base_twr1 = c.getContext("2d");
base_twr1.beginPath();
base_twr1.moveTo(550, 500);
base_twr1.lineTo(300, 500);
base_twr1.lineWidth = 10;
base_twr1.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
base_twr1.closePath();
base_twr1.stroke();

var base_twr2 = c.getContext("2d");
base_twr2.beginPath();
base_twr2.moveTo(900, 500);
base_twr2.lineTo(650, 500);
base_twr2.closePath();
base_twr2.stroke();

var base_twr3 = c.getContext("2d");
base_twr3.beginPath();
base_twr3.moveTo(1250, 500);
base_twr3.lineTo(1000, 500);
base_twr3.closePath();
base_twr3.stroke();


//drawing the towers
var twr1 = c.getContext("2d");
twr1.beginPath();
twr1.moveTo(430, 300);
twr1.lineTo(430, 500);
twr1.closePath();
twr1.stroke();

var twr2 = c.getContext("2d");
twr2.beginPath();
twr2.moveTo(780, 300);
twr2.lineTo(780, 500);
twr2.closePath();
twr2.stroke();

var twr3 = c.getContext("2d");
twr3.beginPath();
twr3.moveTo(1130, 300);
twr3.lineTo(1130, 500);
twr3.closePath();
twr3.stroke();

//array to know each tower what contains
//to avoid collisions
var disks_in_twrs = [];
var twr1_holder = [];
var twr2_holder = [];
var twr3_holder = [];

//start function check the user input
//and call another function if everthing
//is fine 
function btn_start() {
    disks_number = document.getElementById("disk_input").value;
    disks_number = parseInt(disks_number);
    if (disks_number > 0) {
        if (disks_number < 8)
            put_disks(disks_number);
    } else
        alert('write number');

}

var width_disks_start = 305;
var height_disks_start = 490;

var disk_width = 220;

function put_disks(disks) {
    for (i = 0; i < disks; i++) {
        //     var r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256));
        // var g = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256));
        // var b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256)); 

        str1 = "disk";
        width_disks_start = width_disks_start + 10;
        height_disks_start = height_disks_start - 20;

        disk_width = disk_width - 30;

        // eval("disks_in_twrs.push(str1 + i)" );

        // disks_in_twrs[i]=c.getContext("2d");
        // disks_in_twrs[i].rect((Math.random)*100,(Math.random)*100,150,100);
        // disks_in_twrs[i].stroke();
        //  alert(disks_in_twrs);

        twr1_holder.push(str1 + i);

        // ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
        // alert(str1 + i);

        //twr1_holder[i] = c.getContext("2d");
        eval("var disk"+i+"= c.getContext('2d');");
        

        // twr1_holder[i].rect(width_disks_start, height_disks_start, disk_width, 20);
        eval("disk"+i+".rect(width_disks_start, height_disks_start, disk_width, 20);");
        // twr1_holder[i].strokeStyle = "black";
        eval("disk"+i+".strokeStyle = 'black';");
        // twr1_holder[i].stroke();
        eval("disk"+i+".stroke();");


        // alert(disk1.toSource());


    }

}
function hide_me(){
    alert("byeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
    twr1.fillRect(430, 500, 250, 250);
    // disk2.rect(515, 51, 6, 20);

    // disk2.strokeStyle = 'red';

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>tower of Hanoi</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        canvas{
            border : 1px solid black;
        }

        </style>
    </head>
<body>
        <label>how many disk do you want ?</label>
        <input type="text" id="disk_input">
        <button id="start" onclick="btn_start()">start</button>
        <label>note that maximum disk is 8 :P</label>
        <button id="make_hidden" onclick="hide_me()" >make me hide</button>
<canvas id="myCanvas" >
    
</canvas>

<script src="tower.js">

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is `twr1_holder` an array of strings? And where are you trying to access the rectangles after the loop? Can you show that code?

Comment: @mattl. i have try that way to access that way ,by saving in array ,but no result

Comment: Please post all of your code. `twr1_holder` appears to be an array that could hold the data, but why are you using strings and `eval` here?

Comment: @ggorlen i have used to control names ,so that when it eval,it will eval as i want
ex(disk1,disk2,disk3), so i can access them in another function but no result

Comment: You don't need to get a new canvas context each time through the loop. There should only be one drawing context. If you want to save rectangles, you need to be saving objects in an array. You should store the rectangles height, width, x, and y in an object

Comment: @mo.khashab I see that, but why not just execute regular JS directly? You can  use an array of objects with the coords/dimensions/color and be done with it, no `eval`ing of strings necessary.

Comment: @ggorlen can u provide me a tittle that i can search for what u are saying??

Comment: @mattl. i need to access them later one by one

Comment: Right, you can use a `for` loop through the array of rectangle objects

Comment: Thanks for the code--the problem is, it's hard to tell what kind of result you want. Can you draw a sketch or tell us what the result is? I'm assuming this is a Towers of Hanoi app?

Comment: @mattl. so that if i name them as an example disk1,disk2.... i can access them later by for loop, in length of the array , i am sorry if i am not clearing my point but really i tried by best . thanks for your effort u both

Comment: @mo.khashab you don't have to "name" them to loop over them. If you push the objects into an array, then use a for loop or forEach to iterate over that array, you will have access to each one individually. Please completely forget about "eval".

Comment: @ggorlen yes excatly it's , i have start from scratch ,and i want to make it auto-solution , and i want to build them , then it will move one by one

Comment: @DevinFields i will try what have u said .

Comment: @DevinFields i have made what u said and it's done thanks ,if u want to put your answer so u can take a tick ,and thanks for others for their effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot going on here! I recommend attacking each issue in your code separately and building up understanding gradually, because this is an application that requires a lot of different components (DOM manipulation/event handlers, JS canvas, objects/arrays/loops, design, etc). If you're uncomfortable with any of these concepts, pick one area (such as DOM manipulation) and spend time working on simple, understandable examples, then apply what you learned to the main application.

Firstly, almost always avoid `eval` entirely. Mozilla says [never to use it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!)! If you're using it, it probably means your design has gone haywire somewhere along the line, which I would contend is the case here.

As for event handlers and document manipulation, I recommend avoiding `onclick`. Adding event listeners in your script can take care of the job; you'll likely be listening for clicks on the canvas to enable interaction later on.

Next: using canvas. You generally only need to retrieve the context once per application, not before each drawing. Your drawing code looks good other than this, except that it's not very [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), which is usually a signal to redesign.

The hardest part is designing your code to meet your goals, which I'm not entirely clear on. Are you making an interactive Towers of Hanoi app, or one that simply animates a solver algorithm and requires no user input? Either way, I opted to use object constructors to represent Towers and Disks. Using arrays to hold these objects means you identify towers and disks by their position in an array rather than `eval`ing a string name. Whenever you want to perform an action on your towers, such as drawing them, all you need to do is loop through the towers and call `draw` on each one. Later, when it comes to handling user input or writing a solver algorithm, it should be fairly easy to manipulate these arrays to suit your needs (e.g., figuring out which disk was clicked on, moving disks between towers, etc).

Keep in mind the below example is just a quick sketch to get you going and may not follow best design principles or ones that meet your needs. For example, I've hard-coded most drawing coordinate values, so it's non-responsive, so many exercises are left for the reader to improve on.

```js
const Disk = function(width, color) {
  this.width = width;
  this.color = color;
};

const Tower = function(x, disks) {
  this.x = x;
  this.disks = [];
  this.width = 20;
};
Tower.prototype.draw = function(c, ctx) {
  ctx.lineWidth = this.width;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(this.x, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(this.x, c.height);
  ctx.stroke();

  this.disks.forEach((e, i) => {
    ctx.fillStyle = e.color;
    ctx.fillRect(
      this.x - e.width / 2,
      c.height - (i + 1) * this.width,
      e.width, this.width
    );
  });
};

const draw = (c, ctx, towers) => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  towers.forEach(t => t.draw(c, ctx));
};

const initialize = disks => {
  const towers = [
    new Tower(c.width / 5),
    new Tower(c.width / 2),
    new Tower(c.width - c.width / 5)
  ];

  for (let i = disks; i > 0; i--) {
    towers[0].disks.push(
      new Disk(i * 30, `hsl(${Math.random() * 360}, 50%, 50%`)
    );
  }

  return towers;
};

document.getElementById("initialize-form")
  .addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    towers = initialize(parseInt(e.target.elements[0].value), towers);
    draw(c, ctx, towers);
  });

document.getElementById("btn-hide").addEventListener("click",
  e => document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "none"
);

const c = document.getElementById("hanoi");
c.width = 600;
c.height = 200;
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
let towers;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#hanoi {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#initialize-form {
  display: inline-block;
}

#menu {
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <form id="initialize-form">
    <label>Enter disks:</label>
    <input type="number" min="1" max="8" value="6">
    <button type="submit">start</button>
  </form>
  <button id="btn-hide">hide</button>
</div>
<canvas id="hanoi"></canvas>
```

Comment: Nice implementation! but I think that later the largest obstacle is going to be  handling user input / drag & drop, I strongly recommend using a canvas library, see my example on the other answer

Comment: Good suggestion and example, libraries can definitely help with that. I'm not sure the OP is going for interaction though, it's not really clear what the goal will be (it could just be an animation?).

Comment: Ye, not very clear what the goal is, smells a lot like homework troubles

Comment: @ggorlen thanks so much  for your effort, but now if i want to handle a disk in another function,let's suppose i want to let it move, how would i call the object ,i didn't understand how would i do that, and thanks so much for a lot of effort u do , nice implementation and i will really talk your notes in consideration ,and if u can give me an example i would be thankful more, and yes this is assign. and i did't mean to take answer there is a lot ,i just want to understand what is going on.

Comment: @mo.khashab yes, there is quite a lot going on. That step is up to you to determine how to do best, but if it were up to me, I'd start adding functions to my class prototypes. For example, you might want a method that pops the top of one tower stack and appends it on another. You may even want a `Hanoi` class that has this method and encapsulates all the towers. I'm thinking of a header like `Hanoi.moveDisk(sourceTower, destinationTower)`. Hope that points you in the right direction--either way, first absorb the basic knowledge here, then it should be clear how to go about moving disks.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to do you should consider using a canvas library, maybe Konva:
https://konvajs.github.io/

Here is an example:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/2.1.7/konva.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>

<script>
function KonvaRect(x, y, fill, draggable) {
    return new Konva.Rect({
        x: x, y: y, width: 50, height: 50,
        fill: fill, stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4, draggable: draggable
    });
}

var boxes = [];
boxes.push(KonvaRect(50, 10, '#00D2FF', true));
boxes.push(KonvaRect(200, 10, '#0000FF', true));
boxes.push(KonvaRect(125, 10, '#FF0000', false));

var layer = new Konva.Layer();
boxes.forEach(function(b) { layer.add(b) });

var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'container', width: 600, height: 170
});
stage.add(layer);

function moveCenter() {        
    boxes.forEach(function(b) { b.move({ x:0, y: Math.random() * 10 }) });
    layer.batchDraw();
}

boxes[0].on('mouseover', function() {
    moveCenter();
});
</script>
```

On this example I put 3 boxes in an array and when we detect the mouse over the light blue box all boxes move randomly down, also both blue boxes you can click and drag around the canvas.

And for the record there are many many other libraries out there...

Comment: thanks for your effort but no library is allowed , i am trying just to name the objects when i am creating them in for loop,so that i can use them in another place ,and i create one separate ctx and try to move it ,but no result,it create new one without ereasing the original